# Very long redelivery time with ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, connection-pooling

We are using Activemq and PooledConnectionFactory (with spring boot and Camel). 
We are using RedeliveryPolicy and nonBlockingRedelivery.

Is it recommended/possible to have a very long redelivery delay + backoff in our AMQ redelivery.
Is a redelivery for several days/weeks ok with Activemq?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ should be able to handle long redelivery times. However, I would caution you that message brokers like ActiveMQ work best when the messages are consumed relatively quickly so that they don't accumulate excessively in the queues. A message broker should not be treated like a database. Therefore, I'd say your use-case was *possible* but not necessarily recommended.